# Pass property name into method as a string .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, reflection

I'm using LINQ to SQL for a .NET MVC app.

In my db i have a bunch of columns that have "Y" or "N" values in them.

I'm trying to write a general purpose method that will return all the records in the db where `columnName == 'Y'`

So far i've got this

```
public IQueryable<Approved> ReturnRecordsByObjectiveFlag(string columnName)
{       
    return from approved in db.Approved
           where approved.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Equals(columnName)).Equals("Y")
           select approved;
}
```

But that gives me this error

> Member access 'System.String Name' of 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'  not legal on type 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[].

Any idea where i may be going wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `approved`?

Comment: Not fixed, and potentially large amounts of column names. It's Enterprisey.

Comment: Reflection does not work under Linq2SQL. You will have to construct an expression.

Comment: How about Dynamic LINQ? (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx and http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2007/09/18/dynamic-string-based-queries-in-linq.aspx)

Comment: @abatischev The type? Approved is the type. It's a table in my DB

Comment: Yes, the `System.Type t = approved.GetType()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IQueryable<Approved> ReturnRecordsByObjectiveFlag(string columnName)
{   
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Approved), "x");
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Approved,bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, columnName),
            Expression.Constant("Y")
        ), param);
    return db.Approved.Where(predicate);
}
```

---

Edit; if the properties are actually `char?`, i.e. `'Y'` not `"Y"`, then:

```
public IQueryable<Approved> ReturnRecordsByObjectiveFlag(string columnName)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Approved), "x");
    Expression prop;
    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Approved, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            (prop = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, columnName)),
            Expression.Constant(prop.Type == typeof(string) ?
                (object)"Y" : (object)'Y', prop.Type)
        ), param);
    return db.Approved.Where(predicate);
}
```

(this now copes with all of `string`, `char` and `char?`

Comment: Thanks Marc.   i get the error System.InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.Char]' and 'System.String'.

Comment: @Doozer1979: Either fix your question, or fix your DB schema.

Comment: @Doozer1979: Try `Expression.Constant((char?)'Y')`

Comment: @leppie Still the same error. Love to fix the db schema, but sadly that's not my call

Comment: @Doozer1979 - is the property a `string` or a `char` ?

Comment: @Doozer1979 the point @leppie was trying to make there is that you asked about `== "Y"`, but it transpired to be a `char` (or `char?`) - which is `== 'Y'` - a subtle but very important difference.

Comment: @leppie - remember that it is boxed to object, so `(char?)'Y'` and `'Y'` are identical - you need the `Expression.Constant('Y', typeof(char?))` approach (or: cheat like I did)

Comment: @Marc, @Leppie - Ah i see where you were going now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

What is going wrong is that you can't use reflection inside a LINQ query.

How many columns are there - is it a fixed relatively small number?  If so use a switch statement to choose between a number of LINQ queries. This is cleaner and much quicker.

If it's a large number of columns, or they are dynamic,  you could construct a dynamic SQL statement,  but be careful to check for possible injection attacks.

Comment: you can *create* a LINQ query, though

Answer (score 1):

```
approved.GetType().GetProperties()
```

will return a PropertyInfo[] object. Even when you filter it using a `Where` it's still not the value of the property, it's basically a collection of properties that satisfy the critirion, even if that collection has only one member.

To get a specific property by name, you better use the `GetProperty()` method of the Type class, like this:

```
PropertyInfo pi = approved.GetType().GetProperty(columnName);
```

but, you're not done yet. You still have to filter the objects by the value of the property, and that is done by using the `GetValue()` method on the property, like this:

```
bool isApproved = pi.GetValue(approved, null).Equals("Y");
```

or to put everything in your context:

```
return from approved in db.Approved
where approved.GetType().GetProperty(columnName)
                     .GetValue(approved, null).Equals("Y")
select approved;
```

Comment: Was not me, but your answer does not work, as stated in many of the comments already.

Comment: I didn't downvote either. It gives me the error: No overload for method 'GetValue' takes '1' arguments

Comment: Sorry, missed the second parameter when pasting, should work now.

Comment: Unfortunately that still did not work. I've gone with Marc's solution but i appreciate the time and effort you've spent.

Answer (score 0):

- `GetType()` returns `Type`
- `GetProperties()` returns `PropertyInfo[]`
- `Where(..)` returns `IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>`

so you calls

```
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>.Equals(string)
```

that seems to be wrong. Doesn't it?

Answer (score -2):

That is because the last Equals method runs on a filtered IQueryable collection, instead of the property value itself.

Try this instead:

```
return from approved in db.Approved
               where approved.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.Name.Equals(columnName) && (string)x.GetValue(db.Approved, null) == "Y")
               select approved;
```

Comment: -1: Please read the comments/answers already posted to understand why this DOES NOT work.