# returning multiple fields back from a Linq lambda

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I have the following code which returns results back from a database where `columnName = Y'`. The code words fine until i want to limit what fields are returned by the query.

I get the error

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable[AnonymousType#1]' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable[MyApp.Models.Approved]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public IQueryable<Approved> ReturnRecordsByObjectiveFlag(string columnName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Approved), "x");
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Approved, bool>>(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(param, columnName),
                Expression.Constant('Y',typeof(char?))
            ), param);
        return db.Approved.Where(predicate).Select(x =>new{x.RefNo, x.RefGroup, x.Location });
    }
```

it is on this line that i get the error

```
return db.Approved.Where(predicate).Select(x =>new{x.RefNo, x.RefGroup, x.Location });
```

Whereabouts do i make the cast?

Many thanks to Marc Gravell for [Answering an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712947/pass-property-name-into-method-as-a-string-net/4713009#4713009) on this same method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work

```
return db.Approved.Where(predicate).Select(x =>new Approved{x.RefNo, x.RefGroup, x.Location });
```

It gives that error because the select statement is creating an anonymous type

Comment: I did actually try that earlier but i get the error: Cannot initialize type ‘MyApp.Models.Approved' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: You could use property initialisers instead, so : new Approved() { PROPERTYNAME = VALUE, PROP2 = VAL2 etc... } With the properties for your Approved class.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.

```
return db.Approved.Where(predicate).Select(x =>new {x.RefNo, x.RefGroup, x.Location });
```

As it create the anonymous object.